# Does the ending to Watchdogs change based on your reputation?

Tags: watch-dogs

Recently I finished Watchdogs (Thanks EUW for being down a whole day!!) and since I'm pretty sure that you can't replay old missions or the ending itself I have two Questions:

After the Act IV last mission I noticed that

> They show news reports in the credits. Do those change in any way? I realized that mine was about a "Vigilante that helped the people of chicago" since my Rep was rather positive. What happens if you have full positive or even negative reputation?

And also:

> What happens if you kill/spare Maurice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only difference seems to be :

> If you kill Maurice, you miss a little cutscene where Aiden say he can take a new start and quit being a Vigilante. If you kill him, you skip to the credit, news report aren t affected.

Based on different playthought video on youtube.

Here are the two ending:

EDIT:

Reputation does not seem to affect the news report either.

Answer (score 0):

> I had the same news-report after the finale, but my reputation was
>  also top notch.
>  
>  I spared Maurice, but I think it had no effect, because he did not
>  appear again. What did you do?

Comment: Why the down vote? I can of course only speak of my experience, as everyone else.

Comment: Your experience isn't thorough enough to actually answer the question. If you had beat the game repeatedly and compared endings, it might be enough. It's also quite possible to answer from more than just personal experience; other people's experience, video evidence, guides, examination of game assets, etc. can all provide support for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually if your reputation is Menace (like mine) then the new report does not say "Praise for Fox" instead it says how they will have the "strictest enforcement of the law" put on anyone who follows in Aiden Pearce's footsteps as a vigilante. Everything else in the news reports are the exact same including the Ded Sec part

Answer (score 0):

My reputations was anarchist, and instead it said something along the lines of the strictest form of punishment on people like the vigilante. It then showed videos of actual gameplay that I had done of me blowing up cop caras with a grenade launcher.